# How to add icon in input field with jquery?

Tags: jquery, font-awesome

I have input submit button and i want to add icon so that i get  `SEND >`

```
<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>

<input type="submit" value="SEND" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your latest comment you can go through the docs of your [wp-form plugin](http://contactform7.com/submit-button/):

```
<div class="column-full">
     <label>[submit "SEND"]<i class='fa fa-arrow-right'></i></label>
</div>
```

Just add the class to the `input[type='submit']`:

```
<input type="submit" value="SEND" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit fa fa-arrow-right">
```

With jQuery:

```
$('.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit').addClass('fa fa-arrow-right');
```

Comment: @Jai problem is that im using wordpress and this is plugin for contact form and when i declare submit button i need to write like this 
<div class="column-full">[submit "SEND"]</div> so i cant add class directly in submit button

Comment: this add class to submit button but i still dont see arrow... probably i need to use <i id="arrow" class="fa-arrow-right"></i> somehow?

Comment: @None the thing is you can't append the `i` tag in the input but you have to make a sibling like `<input /><i></i>`.

Comment: I guess you have to edit it as per design is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type="submit"]').addClass('fa fa-arrow-right'); // What ever class you required you can add here
})
```